# How can remove adapter from Listview, Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, simpleadapter

I use SimpleAdapter with custom row layout for Listview

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListOrder.this, oslist,
                    R.layout.list_v, 
                    new String[] { "name","time","status" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.tablename, R.id.timeorder, R.id.status});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After , i reload data of Listview and i want remove old data.
I don't know how i can't remove old data before add new data to Listview.

I used

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
```

but have error

> The method remove(Object) is undefined for the type SimpleAdapter

Please help me !
Thank you!

Comment: from the looks of it,it looks like it is like simplecursoradapter which does not have the remove functionality. so you need to remove the item from your database/content provider. and then requery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify the underlying List and inform the adapter about it. Like that:

```
oslist.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

if you only want to remove one or two:

```
oslist.remove(index);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply set

```
listview.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the [Android reference of this function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)) does not say whether a null argument is valid. How do we know that it won't give an exception in some SDK version in the future?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleAdapter does not have remove method so you should extend it to your own adapter and add remove method. E.g.:

```
private class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.data = data;
        //... place some initializing code here
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //place your code for getView here.
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        if (position >= 0 && data.size() < position && data.get(position) != null) {
            data.remove(position);
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

But if you have array of data that is updated (removed || added) regularly, consider using ArrayAdapter (even without your own extension) that has remove() and other methods (example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown ).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I will reference how to use ArrayAdapter . Thank you very much!

Comment: You should call notifyDataSetChanged() after data.remove(position), else it might cause a crash towards the end of your list.